# How to install pymssql on windows with python 2.7?

Tags: python, installation, pymssql

It seems that there are no such binaries yet.
There is an issue on googlecode:
http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/issues/detail?id=12
but i cannot figure out what to do with those files provided.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may also get pymssql2.7 library from this unofficial extensions library

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymssql

Comment: The 64 bit version at that site seems to suffer from [Issue 2](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/issues/detail?id=2), at least on my machine.

Answer (score 5):

If you have pip install:

`pip install pymssql`

To install pip (trust me its very helpful):

1. Download and run this python script (as admin):

   https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: For me, pip was then available in MyPythonDir\Scripts. Thanks Ravish!

Answer (score 4):

Extract the contents into the Python27\Lib\site-packages directory.

Answer (score 4):

Combining YOU and David Huang's answers will bring success; here are some further notes that may help a beginner:

Be sure to download the package that matches the bitness of your windows and also matches the version of Python you are running. I noticed on the pymssql wiki page a note about x64 not being available on Windows so test well if you choose those packages.

It may feel a little sketchy when you notice Christoph Gohlke packages are all exe's. I used WinRAR to open the self-extractor. Inside the archive is a PLATLIB folder which itself contains two files and a folder: `_mssql.pyd`, `pymssql.pyd`, and `pymssql-N.N.N-pyN.N.egg-info`. **These two files and the pymssql-... folder are what needs extracting into `...\Lib\site-packages`.**

Comment: Good post, elaborating on the steps of two other entries (which ideally should not be needed). Unfortunately it didn't work for me: it reported that the pymssql is installed but I wasn't able to import pymmsql (as apparently it wasn't installed; my suspision is that the provided files are currently corrupted somehow). What worked in my case (Cygwin 64bit, Python 2.7 64bit): install FreeTDS 0.91 using the cygwin installer, then installing pymssql of the github repository as described [here](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/432#issuecomment-238257092).