# Finally got pymssql to install, but it won't import

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymssql

I'm use 64-bit windows, Python 2.7 in PyCharm.
The wheel would not install, but I finally got install pymssql by extracting the zip (and instructions I found here: [How to install pymssql on windows with python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666290/how-to-install-pymssql-on-windows-with-python-2-7)) and moving the files into the site-packages folder. Then do "pip install --upgrade pymssql"

But when I go into my python and try doing `import pymssql` it's not recognized. I've installed things with pip before and didn't have so much trouble. Is it because I move files manual to folder? so miss a step somewhere?

Please help. I think pymssql is installed okay, but PyCharm won't import. Is there a way to check install is okay?

Comment: Please check your package installed in default site-packages?

Comment: In PyCharm, `import struct` and then `print("running as {0}-bit".format(struct.calcsize("P") * 8))`. What does it say?

Comment: btw, since I posted my original question, I got this to work just fine on my office computer by justing doing "pip install pymssql", and then in PyCharm just doing "import pymssql"...so I dunno why it's not working on my laptop.

Comment: And it says oh....running as 32-bit erm...okay, my laptop is 64-bit. So I have a 32-bit version of PyCharm? Is that the problem...

Comment: Sorry, every time I hit enter it posts comment. I can't seem to get it to allow me to skip lines now. I'm not sure what you mean Lafada. How do I check that? I still get errors though when I do: "pip install pymsqql" It says...well a bunch of stuff, but it red it says "Failed building wheel for pymssql" Then a bunch more red at bottom, failed with error code 1. But I noticed that it also says platform architecture 32bit, WindowsPE why it say that? It's 64-bit windows...I think this may be the problem. Do I have 32-bit PyCharm? Do I install 64-bit version of PyCharm? Is pip from PyCharm?

Comment: Can you import the module in a Python REPL still, or is Python not able to find it altogether? I think you put it in the wrong folder, as on my Linux installation, all my Python modules seem to be stored in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` rather than `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. I don't know how it is on Windows, though.